# Vaadin (Invalid JSON response from Server - ERROR)

Tags: vaadin

Periodically some users get this error (Invalid JSON response from Server - ERROR), maybe who knows how to solve it?
<vaadin.version>21.0.1</vaadin.version>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIH1N.png)

I have an assumption that it may be a network problem

Comment: Please don't post images. But there is too little information to help you. Can you share your project? You are using an unsupported Vaadin version. You could try to update to the latest version

Comment: That looks like the HTML for the first request. Most likely something redirects, cookies get lost, ... - if you can rule you your runtime, then I'd first update to LTS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)